# Most Efficient Way to Create Scrollable Text Window (Win8 Metro)

Tags: xaml, text, scroll, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am creating a chat windows for a game, and I am using WinRT XAML for the UI.

1.What is the most efficient way to design the chat window to be able to be scrollable and handle multicolored text? At the very least each line should be able to be a separate color. At the moment I have something simple such as:

> ```
> <ScrollViewer x:Name="chatViewScroller" Height="201" Width="475">
>     <StackPanel x:Name="chatViewContent" />
> </ScrollViewer>
> ```

And then as I create new TextBlocks as I need them and add them as children to the chatViewContent. This seems like a very inefficient way of doing things.

2.When I add a new line of text, how do I update the scroller to automatically scroll to the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off using a ListView.

1. Set the ListView's ItemsSource property to an ObservableCollection.
2. Your MessageViewModel would have a Text property as well as Brush.
3. Set your ListView's ItemTemplate to the template below

   ```
   <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock Text={Binding Text} Foreground="{Binding Brush}" />
   </DataTemplate>
   ```
4. When you add a new item to your collection - it will automatically appear in the ListView.
5. To scroll it into view call something like this

   ```
   await Task.Delay(100);
   MyListView.ScrollIntoView(MyListView.Items[MyListView.Items.Count - 1]);
   ```

   You need the delay to wait for the ListView to add the new item.

You can check [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit) for example - specifically the [ListViewExtensionsTestPage](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/13061#268383):

```
    private async void AddItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = (ListViewExtensionsTestViewModel)this.DataContext;
        vm.MyItems.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        // Need to wait for the ListView to update
        await Task.Delay(100);

        SourceListView.ScrollToBottom();
        //SourceListView.ScrollIntoView(SourceListView.Items[SourceListView.Items.Count - 1]);
    }
```

Comment: Is it better to use a list of TextBlocks or use the RichTextBlock? I haven't used the RichTextBlock before, so I don't know any specifics on it.

Comment: I think that depends on how rich you want your content to be. TextBlock already is pretty rich - you can set its Inlines property instead of the Text property and have Run class instances there that use different formatting. I think RichTextBlock might support some more advanced formatting elements like paragraphs and maybe more in the future, but in your case a TextBlock might be enough,

Comment: I don't think I need anything more complicated than setting the color of each line individually. I was just wondering as far as rendering effeciency, which one will be better. Memory may also be a consideration, since this window will contain all chat received since logged on.

Comment: It's a speculation, but TextBlock sounds simpler so it should be lighter in terms of performance overhead/memory use.

Comment: When I use the ListView with TextBlock items, it puts a huge amount of space inbetween each item. How do I get rid of it? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: <ListView.ItemContainerStyle><Style TargetType="ListViewItem"><Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />... Typed on my Windows Phone. ;)

Comment: Erg. I want to make it so that it is only as big as the text (wrapped) is. But I can't seem to get that to work. I tried setting MinHeight. I tried setting Height to Auto. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think having variable height items might not be a recommended design, but I hear you - I was just trying to solve a similar problem, only I decided to give up since I wanted to have a GridView and these really don't work well with variable height items. You could add a behavior that checks for ActualHeight of the content of your ListViewItem and automatically adjusts the height of the ListViewItem. Bindings are not supported in style setters, so you can't do without a workaround (http://blog.xyzzer.me/2011/10/26/workaround-for-binding-not-supported-on-stylesettervalue-in-silverlight/)